# Как точнее детектировать коллизии на высокой скорости движения спрайтов

Tags: java, android

Мне кажется , что эта проблема решаема только, если улучшить характеристики самого андроид гаджета, но всё же может я не прав.

Так вот, есть `Спрайт`, его координата `(x,y)` , есть ускорение `а` . Ускорение меняется так `a = a + 3` , а координаты так `x = x + a`, `y = y + a` .

Всё считается в пикселях. Скорость тут как видите имитируется увеличением шага, который прибавляется к координатам. Когда шаг будет велик (т.е. скорость большая) , два спрайта , которые летят друг другу на встречу, могут проскочить "насквозь" .

Чтобы этого не было и скорость сохранялась, можно увеличить частоту кадров, а шаг, который прибавляется к координатам оставлять как можно меньшим. Но тогда появляется множество других проблем:1)  скорость зависит от фпс , который может выдать то или иное устройство 2) мы не можем поднять фпс до требуемой скорости с 100 процентным детектированием всех коллизий.

Такая же проблема имеется, когда спрайт получает координаты от сенсора устройства. Если провести быстро по сенсору на всю его длину , он отловит например 5 координат , если тащить палец медленно таких координат будет больше. 
(*скорее всего сенсор с определенным временным интервалом сканирует экран на наличие касаний, уменьшить временной интервал и не может и не целесообразно, хотя не плохо бы иметь возможность уменьшать это время в определенном участке кода, а затем снова вернуть, но ведь андроид нам не позволит этого сделать или все же позволит? ответьте на этот вопрос хотя бы теоретически* )

Есть ли другие способы для имитации скорости не теряя возможность качественного детектирования коллизии ?

Если это имеет значение : коллизии я определяю используя теорему о разделяющих осях. Спрайты квадратные.

Наверно можно как то преобразовать и сделать более надежный способ детектирования коллизий хоть и более затратный. Не будет ли в этом случае скорость движения спрайта, на которой 100 процентно детектируются коллизии пропорциональна уменьшению фпс.

Comment: экран это лишь способ отображения, а столкновения считаются на модели. как модель отображается ни как не связано с тем как считаются столкновения.

Comment: Ммм.. интересно интересно. А не укажете какой паттерн подходит? И вообще вы имеете ввиду,  что я могу проделать множество прибавлений шага к координатам, проверять на столкновение,  а потом уже отображать? И еще наверно стоит добавить условие: если коллизия есть, то отобразить.  Так ведь вы предлагаете?

Comment: я вам уже давал ссылку на книгу. там все подробно описано. можете назвать этот петтерн MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендую сделать как в современных игровых движках: сделать два таймера  - один
для проверки коллизий и физики, а другой чисто для рисования.
Так-же в качестве минимального смещения использовать не 1 px, а например 0.01. Скорость обновления физики сделать в 3-4 раза больше рисования.
В рисовании спрайтов можно просто округлять координаты до единиц.